# Haxe - How do you check the hour for a day/night cycle?

Tags: android, haxe

How would one go about checking *just* a 24 hour clock on Android to change an element at a certain time daily? I can't seem to make much of `Date` or `DateTools`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Date.now().getHours();
```

[Returns the hours in 0-23 range](http://api.haxe.org/Date.html#getHours).

Comment: Thanks! You also helped me clear up some fundamental info that just wasn't sticking. Any suggestions for reference outside of the Haxe site?

Comment: Haxe site have pretty solid information and examples. Refer to manual and documantation: https://haxe.org/manual/introduction.html https://haxe.org/documentation/introduction/